# How to check workitem is modified or not before i save

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, workitem

I have problem in saving the workitem. The scenario is i have one web application, from there i am sending value to TFS. I can change value in both the places(through web application also from TFS). The problem i am facing right now is

When i try to save a work item in TFS it checks if there are any changes done since you opened it. If so you are not allowed to save.  There is no such check when i save from web application, i have used workitem.isvalid method, still its not checking the workitem modified before i save it from web application.

This is my code

```
wi.Open();

foreach (var str in piWorkItemTfs.Values.Keys)
    wi[str] = piWorkItemTfs.Values[str];


if (!wi.IsValid())
{
    var listFelaktigaVärde = (from Field field in wi.Validate() select field.Name + "=" + field.Value).ToList();

    errorMessage = "Felaktiga värde: Id " + wi.Id + " " + String.Join(", ", listFelaktigaVärde);
}
else
{
    wi.Save();
    errorMessage = wi.Id.ToString();
}
```

Can any one help me to avoid the concurrency problem please. I need to save the workitem only there is no changes done it before, or else i have show the error message to the end user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IsValid()` method on the work item only validates that the fields on the work item is correct, it does not check whether or not the work item has changed elsewhere. There is a flag on the work item object that is called `IsDirty` which checks to see whether or not the work item has changed since the last save.

As a side note, the fields you display as an error message are only fields that do not adhere to the rules of the work item type definition (i.e. a value of a field that is outside of its defined `AllowedValues`). This should be checked, but a check for whether, or not, it has changed since the last save should display a different error.

Here's a link to MSDN for the `WorkItem` class: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

The `IsDirty` flag will pick up whether, or not, the work item has been modified locally. Instead, the way to check for server-side saves is to try to merge while saving the work item.

```
workItem.Save(SaveFlags.MergeAll);
```

The `IsValid` flag is for local changes, not server changes. Saving the work item with the `SaveFlags.MergAll` option will do the check, and throw the exception if the work item has been saved on the server side.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. I have used IsDirty also, it checks the changed value only after saved. My problem is i have opened the same workitem in two different places same time(one in web application and other in TFS), when i save the workitem first in web and save the save in tfs its giving me error(checking is dirty), but if i save the TFS first and try to save the workitem from web application its not giving any exception, the changed value disappers. i need to show some error before saving(some one modified from outside environment or not)

Comment: Updated the answer to give you the exception.

Comment: hi i cant able to see MergeAll in SaveFlags

Comment: I can able to see only two enum value in saveflags one is none and other is mergelinks, i didnt see any ther values, i have refered using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

Comment: Are you using tfs 2010 or 2012?

Comment: tfs 2010 and visual studio 2012

Comment: Yes, the `MergeAll` option is new in 2012, so your TFS 2010 DLLs will not include this option. You will most likely have to make a server-side call and ensure the revisions are the same before saving the work item.